# Daubechies wavelet transform in Java

Tags: java, opencv, javacv, wavelet

I'm trying to do a 3-level 2D Daubechies wavelet transform on an image and extract the coefficients for each level. I'm using JavaCV right now, but I don't think JavaCV has a Daubechies wavelet transform function. Does anyone know of any Java libraries that I could use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_wavelet_transform:
Complete Java code for a 1-D and 2-D DWT using Haar, Daubechies, Coiflet, and Legendre wavelets is available from the open source project: JWave.
http://code.google.com/p/jwave/